# Cairo dock with what desktop panel

Tags: cairo-dock

I'm using Cairo-Dock 2.4 on Ubuntu 11.10 with the Gnome Classic UI. Is there any other desktop UI I can use that will allow me to just have Cairo-Dock as the main/only panel?  I just need an all-in-one simple panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cairo dock can be "logged into" replacing the gnome-session, this would be a custom Cairo Dock session.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins
```

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/cairo-dock-240-released-with-custom.html

Comment: Yea that's what I figured. The problem with this was that the "menu" bar still appeared on the top of the desktop. (This bar doesn't really serve a purpose). However, I found a fix to that; using advanced settings, I disabled the option to "have file manager handle the desktop." Thanks though. I think I'm sticking to this custom Cairo session.

Answer (score 1):

I use KDE. It's so much more easy and customizable than Gnome. It allows you to have complete control over the panels (removing, resizing, etc.), so that's what I would recommend (Kubuntu). Just open software center, install kubuntu-desktop (you have to click "show hidden files" to be able to see it, and then you can have a desktop with only cairo-dock. Install "lancelot" for Cairo-Dock, to have a menu, and I think that's all you need.

I tried doing this with Gnome before, but after I disabled the Ubuntu Unity plugin in Compiz-Config, I still had an ugly bar at the top with File, View, Edit, and a whole bunch of other junky stuff. Too bad, because I was actually enjoying CCSM more than Kwin, but in the end, I think moving was a good decision--you won't regret it! In fact, you can even user Compiz as your window manager instead of Kwin if you want, although I've never found a need for that.

However, I do have to admit, although I did try pretty hard and researched quite a bit, there still might be a way that I don't know about, so if you don't want to give up Gnome, then keep searching.

Comment: After a little tinkering around, I found this dock called Cinnamon. It's very similar to the Windows task-bar and it is very simplistic and customizable. Somehow, while toggling the "Have file manager handle the desktop" option in advanced settings, that "ugly top bar" disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Off Topic of Cairo-

Docky with Cardapio Mini mode
[image]

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/cardapio-menu-update-brings-docky.html

Comment: Hmm can you run this in its own session?

Comment: I do not believe Docky has that ability yet, Good question.